# How do I force a vertical scrollbar to appear?

Tags: css, margin

My site has both very short and longer pages. Since I center it in the viewport with `margin: 0 auto`, it jumps around a few pixels when switching from a page that has a scrollbar to one that hasn't and the other way around.

Is there a way to force the vertical scrollbar to always appear, so my site stays put when browsing it?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Give your `body` tag an `overflow: scroll;`

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

or if you only want a vertical scrollbar use `overflow-y`

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This is not forcing the scrollbar to "appear", it just adds a scrollbar.

Answer (score 8):

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

This `css` rule causes a vertical scrollbar to always appear.

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/force-vertical-scrollbar/

Comment: In Chrome on Mac OS this does not cause scroll bar to "appear", it merely causes it to "exist".

Comment: I have been doing it this way:

 .element {
  overflow-y: visible;
 }

Painfully simple I know...

Comment: visible [means something else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow): Content is not clipped and may be rendered outside the padding box