# How to always show scrollbars in Dialog React component (Material-UI) when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a React page where users can trigger a [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs) modal window with some content (text) in it. Content can be scrolled (`scroll=paper` is set for Dialog component).

I was following [this example (Scrolling long content)](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#scrolling-long-content) from Material-UI documentation. When I run this example in documentation site — I see scrollbars when I scroll on mobile devices. However, when I click Edit in CodeSandbox and try to run it there ([generated link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vusvx)), I can scroll the content, but scrollbars are **not visible**. For example, on mobile device — an iPhone 6s (iOS 13.3.1) scrollbars are not visible in Safari browser when scrolling, but visible in example in documentation when scrolling. On my site same thing happens, I can't able to show scrollbars.

How to always show native scrollbars when content is being scrolled on all devices in Dialog React component?

Comment: Scrollbars are user and browser specific, meaning you don't get full control over them. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700184/how-do-i-force-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-appear